# Is it possible to call my appication from the native application in Blackberry.?

Tags: blackberry, native

I want to know that is it possible to call my application from the native app. like Reminder,phone call etc. in Blackberry.
It yes then please give me sort description about how it is possible.

Comment: So do you want to call reminder app from your app??

Comment: i want to do it reverse.Means i want to call my app from reminder(when reminder invokes) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes ,it is possible.
you can add your menu item in native application,and on run method pass the argument to perform your task.

to add menu item use it.

```
 AdressBookMenuItem menuItem = new AdressBookMenuItem(0);
    ApplicationMenuItemRepository repository =ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance();
    long id=ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_CALENDAR;
    repository.addMenuItem(id2,menuItem);
```

and for open your app

```
   class AdressBookMenuItem extends ApplicationMenuItem {

Message mess;

public AdressBookMenuItem(int order) {
    super(order);
}

public AdressBookMenuItem(Object context, int order) {
    super(context, order);
}
public Object run(Object mess) 
{
    ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launch(appCodName+"?admin");
 }

public String toString() {
    return "MENU Item name";
}
   }
```

Comment: thanx,is it possible to do so for reminder bcz there isnt any menuitem for reminder when it invokes

Comment: k,i think this is the only way to do so,u can add your menu item wherever you want,if there not exist any menu item then add yours there.